# kdb - truncate subsequent rows based on point of data

Tags: kdb

All,
I'm having  trouble solving for what I believe to be a fairly straightforward task to search a table, identify a point and then truncate or delete the subsequent rows for a set of data within a table. I believe I need a nested function in my update query however I have not been successful writing one. I've also tried to create a "delete_me" column as well which will allow me to identify and then run a single delete which may be faster and better for auditing code as well.

Ideally, I'd like to wrap this in a callable function as there are a few different methods of truncation.

In my example below, I identify the maximum cumulative value date and then label the subsequent dated rows by id for eventual deletion.

```
///raw data for copy and paste - `:./Data/sample.csv;
id,idate,a,b,c
AAA,1/31/2014,1000,500,500
AAA,2/28/2014,900,500,50
AAA,3/31/2014,850,500,0
AAA,4/30/2014,800,500,0
AAA,5/31/2014,750,500,0
AAA,6/30/2014,700,500,0
AAA,7/31/2014,650,500,0
AAA,8/31/2014,550,500,0
AAA,9/30/2014,500,500,0
AAA,10/31/2014,450,500,0
BBB,6/30/2012,1000,500,2500
BBB,7/31/2012,950,500,75
BBB,8/31/2012,900,500,0
BBB,9/30/2012,850,500,0
BBB,10/31/2012,800,500,0
BBB,11/30/2012,750,500,0
BBB,12/31/2012,700,500,0
BBB,1/31/2013,650,500,0
BBB,2/28/2013,600,500,0
BBB,3/31/2013,550,500,0
BBB,4/30/2013,500,500,0
BBB,5/31/2013,450,500,0
BBB,6/30/2013,400,500,0
CCC,1/1/2016,1000,500,1200
CCC,2/29/2016,950,500,30
CCC,3/31/2016,900,500,0
CCC,4/30/2016,850,500,0
CCC,5/31/2016,800,500,0
CCC,6/30/2016,750,500,0
CCC,7/31/2016,700,500,0
CCC,8/31/2016,650,500,0
CCC,9/30/2016,600,500,0
CCC,10/31/2016,550,500,0
CCC,11/30/2016,500,500,0
CCC,12/31/2016,450,500,0
CCC,1/31/2017,400,500,0
CCC,2/28/2017,350,500,0
CCC,3/31/2017,300,500,0
CCC,4/30/2017,250,500,0
```

Load data and add some calculations

```
\c 100 150i
t:("SSFFF";enlist",") 0:`:./Data/sample.csv;
t: update kdbDate: "D"$string idate, d:(a-(b+c)),cum_d: sums (a-(b+c)) from t;
t:![t; (); (enlist`id)!enlist`id; (enlist`maxCum_d)!enlist(max;`cum_d)];
t:![t; enlist(=;`maxCum_d;`cum_d); (enlist`id)!enlist`id; (enlist `date_cutoff)!enlist(*:;`kdbDate)];
```

Below is where I'm presently stuck. I've also thought of using `fills` to just fill in the `date_cutoff` for the remaining rows per `id` as well and avoid creating another column altogether.

```
show exec max(date_cutoff) by id from t;
assignDelete:{[t] update del: `delete_me by id from t where max (date_cutoff) > kdbDate}; //<--STUCK--
t: assignDelete over t;
t:![t; enlist (~:;(^:;`del)); 0b; `symbol$()] ; //delete from t where not null `del
```

Many thanks in advance! Desired output below

```
q)t
id  idate      a    b   c    kdbDate    d     cum_d maxCum_d date_cutoff del      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA 1/31/2014  1000 500 500  2014.01.31 0     0     1650                 
AAA 2/28/2014  900  500 50   2014.02.28 350   350   1650                 
AAA 3/31/2014  850  500 0    2014.03.31 350   700   1650                 
AAA 4/30/2014  800  500 0    2014.04.30 300   1000  1650                 
AAA 5/31/2014  750  500 0    2014.05.31 250   1250  1650                 
AAA 6/30/2014  700  500 0    2014.06.30 200   1450  1650                
AAA 7/31/2014  650  500 0    2014.07.31 150   1600  1650                 
AAA 8/31/2014  550  500 0    2014.08.31 50    1650  1650     2014.08.31  
AAA 9/30/2014  500  500 0    2014.09.30 0     1650  1650     2014.08.31  delete_me
AAA 10/31/2014 450  500 0    2014.10.31 -50   1600  1650                 delete_me
BBB 6/30/2012  1000 500 2500 2012.06.30 -2000 -400  1775                 
BBB 7/31/2012  950  500 75   2012.07.31 375   -25   1775                 
BBB 8/31/2012  900  500 0    2012.08.31 400   375   1775                 
BBB 9/30/2012  850  500 0    2012.09.30 350   725   1775                 
BBB 10/31/2012 800  500 0    2012.10.31 300   1025  1775                 
BBB 11/30/2012 750  500 0    2012.11.30 250   1275  1775                 
BBB 12/31/2012 700  500 0    2012.12.31 200   1475  1775                 
BBB 1/31/2013  650  500 0    2013.01.31 150   1625  1775                 
BBB 2/28/2013  600  500 0    2013.02.28 100   1725  1775                 
BBB 3/31/2013  550  500 0    2013.03.31 50    1775  1775     2013.03.31   
BBB 4/30/2013  500  500 0    2013.04.30 0     1775  1775     2013.03.31   delete_me
BBB 5/31/2013  450  500 0    2013.05.31 -50   1725  1775                  delete_me
BBB 6/30/2013  400  500 0    2013.06.30 -100  1625  1775                  delete_me
CCC 1/1/2016   1000 500 1200 2016.01.01 -700  925   3145                 
CCC 2/29/2016  950  500 30   2016.02.29 420   1345  3145                 
CCC 3/31/2016  900  500 0    2016.03.31 400   1745  3145                 
CCC 4/30/2016  850  500 0    2016.04.30 350   2095  3145                 
CCC 5/31/2016  800  500 0    2016.05.31 300   2395  3145                 
CCC 6/30/2016  750  500 0    2016.06.30 250   2645  3145                 
CCC 7/31/2016  700  500 0    2016.07.31 200   2845  3145                 
CCC 8/31/2016  650  500 0    2016.08.31 150   2995  3145                 
CCC 9/30/2016  600  500 0    2016.09.30 100   3095  3145                 
CCC 10/31/2016 550  500 0    2016.10.31 50    3145  3145     2016.10.31  
CCC 11/30/2016 500  500 0    2016.11.30 0     3145  3145     2016.10.31  delete_me
CCC 12/31/2016 450  500 0    2016.12.31 -50   3095  3145                 delete_me
CCC 1/31/2017  400  500 0    2017.01.31 -100  2995  3145                 delete_me
CCC 2/28/2017  350  500 0    2017.02.28 -150  2845  3145                 delete_me
CCC 3/31/2017  300  500 0    2017.03.31 -200  2645  3145                 delete_me
CCC 4/30/2017  250  500 0    2017.04.30 -250  2395  3145                 delete_me
```

**[EDIT] using `fills` on another column seemed to work okay.**
Note truncation after the max(cum_d)

```
t: update del:fills date_cutoff by id from t where kdbDate>date_cutoff;
or in functional form
t: ![t; enlist(>;`kdbDate;`date_cutoff);(enlist`id)!enlist`id;(enlist`del)! enlist (^\;`date_cutoff)];


id  idate      a    b   c    kdbDate    d     cum_d maxCum_d date_cutoff del
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA 1/31/2014  1000 500 500  2014.01.31 0     0     1650
AAA 2/28/2014  900  500 50   2014.02.28 350   350   1650
AAA 3/31/2014  850  500 0    2014.03.31 350   700   1650
AAA 4/30/2014  800  500 0    2014.04.30 300   1000  1650
AAA 5/31/2014  750  500 0    2014.05.31 250   1250  1650
AAA 6/30/2014  700  500 0    2014.06.30 200   1450  1650
AAA 7/31/2014  650  500 0    2014.07.31 150   1600  1650
AAA 8/31/2014  550  500 0    2014.08.31 50    1650  1650     2014.08.31
BBB 6/30/2012  1000 500 2500 2012.06.30 -2000 -400  1775
BBB 7/31/2012  950  500 75   2012.07.31 375   -25   1775
BBB 8/31/2012  900  500 0    2012.08.31 400   375   1775
BBB 9/30/2012  850  500 0    2012.09.30 350   725   1775
BBB 10/31/2012 800  500 0    2012.10.31 300   1025  1775
BBB 11/30/2012 750  500 0    2012.11.30 250   1275  1775
BBB 12/31/2012 700  500 0    2012.12.31 200   1475  1775
BBB 1/31/2013  650  500 0    2013.01.31 150   1625  1775
BBB 2/28/2013  600  500 0    2013.02.28 100   1725  1775
BBB 3/31/2013  550  500 0    2013.03.31 50    1775  1775     2013.03.31
CCC 1/1/2016   1000 500 1200 2016.01.01 -700  925   3145
CCC 2/29/2016  950  500 30   2016.02.29 420   1345  3145
CCC 3/31/2016  900  500 0    2016.03.31 400   1745  3145
CCC 4/30/2016  850  500 0    2016.04.30 350   2095  3145
CCC 5/31/2016  800  500 0    2016.05.31 300   2395  3145
CCC 6/30/2016  750  500 0    2016.06.30 250   2645  3145
CCC 7/31/2016  700  500 0    2016.07.31 200   2845  3145
CCC 8/31/2016  650  500 0    2016.08.31 150   2995  3145
CCC 9/30/2016  600  500 0    2016.09.30 100   3095  3145
CCC 10/31/2016 550  500 0    2016.10.31 50    3145  3145     2016.10.31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this solution I've left-joined `date_cutoff` by `id` to the table so that all `date_cutoff` entries are non-null, then used a vector conditional to determine whether to delete or not.

```
q)t:t lj select last date_cutoff by id from t where not null date_cutoff
q)update del:?[date_cutoff<kdbDate;`delete_me;`]from t
```

So long as there is only one distinct `date_cutoff` within an `id` grouping, this should work.

Comment: Thanks Cathal. I just saved an edit that works using `fills` command but it isn't as smooth.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `maxs` function calculates the running maximum value of a given vector. You can avoid adding those auxiliary columns altogether by leveraging this with an `fby` where clause:

```
// define the table
q)t:("SSFFF";enlist",") 0:`:./Data/sample.csv;
q)t: update kdbDate: "D"$string idate, d:(a-(b+c)),cum_d: sums (a-(b+c)) from t;

// delete rows with one q-sql statement
q)delete from t where ({prev max[x]=maxs[x]};cum_d) fby id
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge!  That certainly is more streamlined as well. I've been reading and trying to find places to use `fby` but really haven't successfully implement it yet. My table is so wide I'm trying to reduce the columns so this is very helpful. Now that I have all my foundational data set, i expect to use it as I intend to aggregate metrics by `id`. For example, I'm running various metrics and aggregate functions by `id`  (IRR, breakeven price, ROE, etc). as each `id` represents a decision compared. Then I'll look at the same metrics on various groupings of `id`. Thanks again!